# Add a new category to Data Frame

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have dataframe which is like the below. The values are percentages. I would like to add "Others" category which will be 100 - sum of the column values. I have used the following approach:

```
Research = pd.read_csv('.../TeenResearch.csv')
Research
```

Research Area             Adults       Teens

0   Alternative Energy    33             23

1   Stem Cell Research     12            4

2   Water purification     11           20

3   Space Exploration   3        15

```
Research.loc['Others'] =Research.sum()

# append sums to the data frame
Research.append(Others,ignore_index=True)
```

But I would like the output of data frame to be

Research Area   Adults  Teens

0   Alternative Energy  33  23

1   Stem Cell Research  12  4

2   Water purification  11  20

3   Space Exploration   3   15

4   Others             41   28

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
Research.loc[len(Research)] = ['Others', 100-Research.Adults.sum(),100-Research.Teens.sum() ]
```